# how to Format Date from "2017-11-18T06:45:00.000Z" to "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM " using es6?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

The data base is returning date as "2015-01-17T05:30:00.000Z"
I want to convert it to "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM" format. How do I do it using plain javascript(es6) without using momentjs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the code you've already tried and we'll be happy to help you get it working.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome @Alien Bishop, luckily we started using momentjs and there will be no need of plain javascript function for now. please help others by writing a relative function